# Bind data from REST service to ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

im trying to create `ComboBox` populated with data that I got from REST service.

In my window I have method to get data and set ViewModel:

```
private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String url = "http://localhost:8081/HTTP/testFrigoexim/prijem/getDodavatele";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            String response = client.DownloadString(url);
            Dodavatele dodavatele;

            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dodavatele));
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response)))
            {
                dodavatele = (Dodavatele)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            }

            ComboBoxDodavatele.DataContext = new ViewModel(dodavatele);
        }
```

Class represents data from REST service:

```
namespace TestovaciAplikace.Prijem
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Dodavatele
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<Dodavatel> dodavatele { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dodavatel
    {
        public string CODE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and last class, `ViewModel`

```
namespace TestovaciAplikace.Prijem
{
    public class ViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Dodavatele dodavatele { get; set; }

        public ViewModel(Dodavatele dodavatele)
        {
            this.dodavatele = dodavatele;
        }
    }
}
```

Binding into ComboBox is

```
 <ComboBox Name="ComboBoxDodavatele" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Height="35"
                  Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding dodavatele}" DisplayMemberPath="CODE"/
```

If I run program, `ComboBox` is empty. If I replace ny `ViewModel` to return only simple `List<String>` it works (if I change binding properties), but I cant get it work with my JSON data. Any advice?

Comment: Oh man, thanks! Change it and it look like it works! If you post it as answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the ViewModel and the Dodavatele class have a `dodavatele` property, the ItemsSource Binding should look like this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding dodavatele.dodavatele}"
```